# Weird badge award

Tags: bug

I got an Announcer badge for sharing the IP address of [Filter coefficients for colored noise Voss Algorithm](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/1100/235) which caused 25 different users to visit the question. But I have no recollection of ever having read the question, and cannot think of any reason why I would have shared its IP address with anyone or mentioned it in one of my own answers. Indeed, until I got the badge. I had never even heard of the Voss algorithm.  So what's going on?

Comment: That IP stuff is about counting the number of individual people who followed the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You link to it in your comment to [your answer to question *Applying FIR filter to data with different sample rates*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1105/15347). One can't remember everything, I guess. The title of the question [was also edited](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/1100/revisions), so maybe you saw it without a mention of "Voss algorithm".

Comment: Thanks. I actually linked to the _answer_ by schnarf, and not to the question itself, and while looking at the question itself was puzzled as to why I would link to it.